# Raspbian retains last uuid ownership at mount, but where?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, mount

The following commands give user `user2` rw acces to an external usb drive :

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/user/mnt/my_mount
sudo chown user2:user2 /home/user/mnt/my_mount
```

Command `umount` sets ownership back to user `user` for file `my_mount`

However re-mounting again with

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/user/mnt/my_mount
```

sets again ownership to `user2` without the need of `chown`. Even after reboots, or mount-point changes the mount command sets ownership back to `user2`. Also the automount in `/media/pi/` of `/dev/sda1` gets also `user2` ownership for the next reboots.

It seems that the mount command stores somewhere the last ownership of an **uuid**, set by the last `chown` done on a mount-point where the device **uuid** was mounted.

Is it so ? And if so where is the "**uuid**  ownership" stored ?

Comment: This question does not belong to Raspberry Pi. You have to distinguish between the permissions of the mount point and the permissions of the mounted device. If unmounted you see the permissions of the mount point, if mounted you see them from the mounted device. The permissions of that are stored on the device.

Comment: @Ingo thank you for the clarification, now that you reminded the permissions are stored on the device, it is obvious.

Comment: DO NOT add detail in comments to answers; edit your question. The standard form of the mount command is: `mount -t type device dir` - read `man mount`. Your question is unclear, and you have provided no evidence of your alleged problem, or detail of what is being mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Once you run

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /home/user/mnt/my_mount
```

`/home/user/mnt/my_mount` is replaced by the root directory of `/dev/sda1`. So, when you run

```
sudo chown user2:user2 /home/user/mnt/my_mount
```

you don't change the ownership of the original `/home/user/mnt/my_mount`. Instead, you set the ownership of the root directory of `/dev/sda1`. This information is then persistenly saved on `/dev/sda1`.